# Can you have the same Django App on two different servers?

Tags: django, django-models

Can I have a Django App on Machine A, which takes care of all the routing and the same "stripped" App on Machine B (with some more computation power) that's only used for running jobs to modify some fields of a model thus don't have all the views, templates etc. but only used to call some `MyModel.objects.get(user=my_user).save()`?

Comment: Typically you let these point to the same database then. You can also work with a replication database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing)#DATABASE

Comment: Yes, they indeed need to point to the same database. It's simply such that I'm able to update values in the database but fr another machine

Answer (score 0):

as long as they point to the same database, you are good. you should know how to redirect your urls though.

Comment: The URL should only be handled by Machine A - the external machine would only consist of the model file and one function which does some model-update (apart from the required files of course).

Comment: It doesn't matter which machine handles what.  An manipulation on the db will work and show in both machines as long as they are connected to the same db.